# What happens if you buy a potion after getting Sozu?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The Sozu relic's description says you can no longer obtain potions. However, I see that I can still buy potions from the shopkeeper.

What happens if you buy a potion from the shop after getting the Sozu relic?

[image: Shopkeeper screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy the potion, but you won't actually receive it. The potion just gets absorbed by the Suzu. You'll lose the money you spent on it.

Comment: Can confirm from experience.